# Using a replace pattern in preg_replace replacement parameter

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to use PHP's `preg_replace` to replace every `#CODE-123` kind of token to `/CODE-123`.

It works pretty well except for one last detail, I'd need to remove the `#` from the string the second time I use it but I cannot figure out how.

Here's what I have so far:

```
echo preg_replace('/#.*-[0-9]*/i', '[${0}](/${0})', $this->description);
```

It works and replaces #CODE-123 to `[#CODE-123](/#CODE-123)` but I'd need it to be `[#CODE-123](CODE-123)` instead.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: kingkero has the answer. As an aside comment, I suggest you to replace `.*` by something else more explicit, this will reduce the regex engine work and avoid possible errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you group it (with brackets `(..)`), you can address each of the found independently

```
echo preg_replace('/#(.*-[0-9]*)/i', '[${0}](${1})', $this->description);
```

The whole pattern will always be recognized by `0` (what you already use), and the first group by `1`, etc. You might want to add `?` to make the pattern not greedy.

Currently it works like this:

```
$text = "hello world #ACODE-123 blabla #BCODE-233";
echo preg_replace('/#(.*-[0-9]*)/i', '[${0}](${1})', $text);
//hello world [#ACODE-123 blabla #BCODE-233](ACODE-123 blabla #BCODE-233)
```

Which is most likely not the wanted result (but valid!).

```
$text = "hello world #ACODE-123 blabla #BCODE-233";
echo preg_replace('/#(.*?-[0-9]*)/i', '[${0}](${1})', $text);
                 //     ^-- this is new
//hello world [#ACODE-123](ACODE-123) blabla [#BCODE-233](BCODE-233)
```